# Meteor 1.3 + React indeterminate <script> load order

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use a template I purchased on themeforest that came with a bunch of js and css files.

In my `client/main.html`, I have the following code just before the end of body tag:

[image]

The react app is mounted into `div#app` via react-router.

App var in `app.js` is referenced in `layout.js`, `demo.js` and `quick-sidebar.js` and is supposed to be loaded first. I have placed a log statement in each of four js files. Each time I refresh the page, I get a different load sequence:

Page refreshed:
[image]

Page refreshed again: 
[image]

Page refreshed yet again: 
[image]

Inspecting the page shows the scripts in the right order on the page:
[image]

Here is my directory structure. All files I received from themeforest are in the public folder:

[image]

**As far as I know, the scripts are supposed to load synchronously and be blocking until the entire script has loaded. This does not seem to be the case here. I need to ensure the load order. What am I missing here?**

Thanks.

Comment: My main confusion is: Why is the <script/> load order as listed in the main.html file not obeyed. Is there something special about meteor or react that is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this info  can help you:

According to the Meteor documentation, files are currently loaded in this order:

1. Files in [project_root]/lib are loaded first
2. Files are sorted by directory depth. Deeper files are loaded first.
3. Files are sorted in alphabetical order.
4. main.* files are loaded last.

Source: http://docs.meteor.com/#struc

And also here:
http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking to use the template files without modifying their names. If I place the files in lib, I will need to modify/prefix the names of the files to make them obey meteor load rules. Also, my main confusion still remains: Why is the <script/> load order as listed in the main.html file not obeyed. Is there something special about meteor or react that is causing this behavior?